# Match Pattern and Replace in HTML tags

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

```
    </tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:yellow" ><td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.13</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.86</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >8</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA5.12</td>
</tr>
```

Want to  find NehaA between `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags then change

```
`<tr class='htmllist_tr'>`
```

or

```
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:yellow">
```

to

```
`<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red">` *
```

tried this

```
sed -e "/NehaA/ s/\'<tr class='htmllist_tr'>\'/\'<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red">\'/ ;" 2932_TABLE2.txt
```

didn't work please help

Comment: Doing it in awk/sed is not the best idea. Why don't you use Python+Beautiful Soup? In perl you can use (I think, I haven't use it before) HTML::Parser.

Comment: HTML, like XML, is structured data. You mustn't treat it as an ordinary text file. There are [many modules available](http://search.cpan.org/search?m=module&q=html) that will parse your HTML and allow you to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get a usable answer using an HTML parser then try this:

```
$ awk -v RS='</tr>\\s*' '/Neha/{ORS=RT; sub(/<tr[^>]+>/,""); print "<tr class=\047htmllist_tr\047 style=\"background-color:red\">" $0}' file
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red"><td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.13</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.86</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red"><td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >8</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA5.12</td>
</tr>
```

It uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT.

Comment: Thank you Much its showing only those records which has NehaA

Comment: Also there is no line break in </tr> and next <tr class>

Comment: It's very important for the sample input/output you post to truly reflect you real sample input/output so when we test a potential solution we can tell at a glance if it does what you want or not. idk what you mean by `there is no line break in </tr> and next <tr class>` - are you saying your input is wrong or my output is wrong or something else? Please edit your question to show sample input/output that demonstrates the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm). The code itself is self exaplanatory. I will suggest you to read the documentations as it is not recommended to parse HTML [`using regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $str = <<'HTML'
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:yellow" >
<td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.13</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.86</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' >
<td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >8</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA5.12</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
HTML
;


my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($str);

my @tr = $root -> find_by_tag_name('tr');

foreach (@tr) {
    if ($_ -> find_by_attribute("class","htmllist_tr")) {
       my @tds = $_ -> look_down(_tag => 'td', class => 'htmllist_td');
       my @children = map {$_ -> content_list} @tds;
       if(grep(/NehaA/, @children)) {
           $_ -> attr('style', 'background-color:red');
       }
    }
}

print $root -> as_HTML(undef, "  ");
```

Comment: Thank you Arunesh.I have never used HTML::TreeBuilder will try this

Answer (score 0):

@ED ..sorry for the cofusion ..this is the original file

```
<table  class='htmllist'>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><th class='htmllist_th' >TABLESPACE<br>NAME</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >ALLOCATED<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>PCT</th>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:yellow" ><td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.78</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.93</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >TEMP</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >125</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >124.63</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >99.7</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >TEMP_EDDDATA</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >205.99</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >198.52</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >96.37</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >22.85</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA14.62</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I Want output like

```
<table  class='htmllist'>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><th class='htmllist_th' >TABLESPACE<br>NAME</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >ALLOCATED<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>PCT</th>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red" ><td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.78</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.93</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >TEMP</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >125</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >124.63</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >99.7</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' ><td class='htmllist_td' >TEMP_EDDDATA</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >205.99</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >198.52</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >96.37</td>
</tr>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red"><td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >22.85</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA14.62</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

however when I am using this

```
awk -v RS='</tr>\\s*' '/Neha/{ORS=RT; sub(/<tr[^>]+>/,""); print "<tr class=\047htmllist_tr\047 style=\"background-color:red\">" $0}' text.txt
```

this is giving me output like this

```
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red"><table  class='htmllist'>
<th class='htmllist_th' >TABLESPACE<br>NAME</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >ALLOCATED<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>GB</th>
<th class='htmllist_th' >CURRENT<br>FREE<br>SPACE<br>PCT</th>
<tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:yellow" ><td class='htmllist_td' >INDX01</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >964.87</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >95.78</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA9.93</td>
</tr><tr class='htmllist_tr' style="background-color:red">
<td class='htmllist_td' >UNDOTBS1</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >156.25</td>
<td class='htmllist_td_nbr' >22.85</td>
<td class='htmllist_td' >NehaA14.62</td>
</tr>
```

let me know if this make sense

Comment: Please add these details to your question instead of answer. Secondly, You can give `HTML::TreeBuilder` a try. It will give you, your expected *output*. It is not a good habit to parse html with *regex*; it'd break somewhere. Do tell me, if you have any doubts.